# ifdown cannot see my WiFi interface (kubuntu 16.04.3)

Tags: networking, kubuntu

So I'm trying to a very simple command (ifdown) to bring down my WiFi interface but the command cannot see it (see below)

When I ran the ifdown command, I copy/paste the interface name from the results of the iwconfig so it's very unlikely I made a typo. I've done this several times and I get the same results.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks

```
user@mydesktop:~/$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4915 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4915 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:413384 (413.3 KB)  TX bytes:413384 (413.3 KB)

wls1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:13:e8:63:3d:cd  
          inet addr:192.168.1.11  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::19a:7204:6f13:7593/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:62390 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43986 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:79936235 (79.9 MB)  TX bytes:5382829 (5.3 MB)

chiyo@mydesktop:~/$ iwconfig
wls1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"XXXXX"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 80:EA:96:F2:4A:E2   
          Bit Rate=57.8 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:2   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

user@mydesktop:~/$ sudo ifdown wls1
ifdown: interface wls1 not configured
```

Comment: If your interface is configured by Network Manager, you should manage it my `nmcli`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interface is probably configured using Network Manager.

In this case you can disable it by e.g. (there are other ways).

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

Then you can check the result by `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 4):

The command `ifdown` is reserved for interfaces which are configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Yours is configured in Network Manager instead. I suggest that you use:

```
sudo ifconfig wls1 down
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iproute2 command:

```
sudo ip link set wls1 down
```

As montioned [@chilli555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555) "ifdown is reserved for interfaces which are configured in /etc/network/interfaces"